# How to post a value to other page using link, without using hidden type?

Tags: php, jquery

I want post a value by clicking the link, which re-directs to another page. I want to get the value in the re-directed page using `$_POST` method in `PHP` . But I don't wish to use hidden type, Is there any other way in `JQuery` or `PHP`?

Comment: clicking link, as in href, or using an input/button? your question's about as clear as mud at midnight.

Comment: link, as in href, I am sorry, I am not quite good in English..

Comment: href, aka hyperlink https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a which is something you should know. HTML 101; learn the terminologies if you want to become a coder/developer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to submit `POST` data without using a Form and the `hidden` data type, then you might consider using a jQuery plugin like [**redirect**](https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect/blob/master/jquery.redirect.js).

You can redirect like so:

`$().redirect('newPage.php', {'name': 'Jack'});`

And then access the variable from `newPage`'s PHP with the standard `$_POST["name"]` style call.

In your situation, if you want to intercept a link click, you'll be much better of using jQuery.

```
$("#myLink").click(function(){
    $().redirect('newPage.php', {'name': 'Jack'});
});
```

**Alternatively**, you also have `$_SESSION`, which enables you to store a variable on one page, then retrieve it on another, but in your situation this will be harder to achieve (I'm including it for reference only).

*Page 1:*

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["name"] = "Jack";
```

*Page 2:*

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["name"];
```